# Splitting column into two columns in each row (and add headers)

Tags: html, angularjs

I need split one field in some column, e.g

```
[A1] [B1] [C1] [D1] [E1]
[A2] [B2] [C2] [D2] [E2]
........
```

I would like transorm it to

```
[A1] [B1] [C1] [D1] [E1_1|E1_2]
[A2] [B2] [C2] [D2] [E2_1|E2_2]
.....
```

The simplified fragment of my code looks like:

```
   <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>HEAD_A</th>
            <th>HEAD_B</th>
            <th>HEAD_C</th>
            <th>HEAD_D</th>
            <th>HEAD_E</th>                 
            <th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in myCtrl.rows>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The additional requirement and key is to add headers for this two columns (these two columns are nested in some field, ane are created via splitting).

Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Can you please provide a valid JSON representation of your myCtrl.rows array?

Comment: It is simple list of numbers.

Comment: @HaskellFun The column you want to split, how will the data of the column being split look like?

Comment: You should show us incoming data, desired html output and corresponding transformation rules from one to another. Without it, we can't help you.